# Different IdentityUser.ConcurrencyStamp values between 2 browsers reading the DB

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity

The fundamental problem I'm hitting is I am not getting a DbUpdateConcurrencyException when I have one browser updating before another. Diving into the problem what I am finding is, in each browser I get the IdentityUser as follows:

```
IdentityUser? identityUser;
await using (var context = await _userDbFactory.CreateDbContextAsync())
{
    identityUser = await context.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.Id == userid);
    if (identityUser == null)
        return null;
}
```

The returned identityUser object has all properties in the two browsers with the same value except identityUser.ConcurrencyStamp . That is different.

And if I refresh the browsers, causing each to initialize again, they still have the distinct values. The values remain the same for refresh after refresh, but different between the two browsers.

I started a third browser and it matches the second browser.

And again, there's nothing else touching this. And a refresh which then calls OnInitializedAsync(), keeps giving the same value for ConcurrencyStamp in each browser.

Just tested something else - updating the record does not change the value of the ConcurrencyStamp. Isn't the DB supposed to be changing this on any update? The other properties that were changed are updated in the record.

I tested against my DB models with a  `[Timestamp]` and they work as expected. So it's just this.

I save the edited record as follows:

```
await using (var context = await UserDbFactory.CreateDbContextAsync())
{
  var entry = context.Users.Attach(identityUser);
  entry.Property(iu => iu.ConcurrencyStamp).IsModified = true;
  identityUser.Email = identityUser.UserName = AccountPageModel.Email;
  string normalizedEmail = AccountPageModel.Email.ToUpperInvariant();
  identityUser.NormalizedEmail = identityUser.NormalizedUserName = normalizedEmail;
  identityUser.EmailConfirmed = false;
  await context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

How can this happen?